# Minimal block system in GAP software

Tags: group-actions, gap

I want to list down all minimal block system, I am trying "Blocks(G,[1..4]);" command but it is not giving minimal block system. Let $G=\langle (12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23) \rangle$
$$\pi: G \times [4] \mapsto [4]$$

**Minimal block system :** First consider the group action ($\phi$) of $G$ on $[n]$, then we will be get the blocks , so we need to refine $G$ means at the second level from the leafs, we will consider the action of group $G/Ker(\phi)$ and so on.

Is there any inbuilt command to print all minimal block systems? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `RepresentativesMinimalBlocks(G,MovedPoints(G))`. It will give for each block system the block containing $1$. If $r$ is such a block `Orbit(g,Set(r),OnSets)` will return the full block system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, RepresentativesMinimalBlocks(G,MovedPoints(G)) is not working. it is not giving the minimal block system.

Comment: @sssss Can you give me a concrete example of what is not working (group generators and the error message you get)? -- possibly just by personal mail.

Comment: @ ahulpke Sorry . It is working correctly, it was my mistake.